# Check if bean is null in iBatis using dynamic mapped statements

Tags: java, sql, database, ibatis

i want to check if the bean that i use as parameter is null using dynamic statements.

```
<select id="my-query" resultClass="my.package.Results" parameterClass="my.package.Bean">
     //MY QUERY
</select>
```

There is a way to check if my bean is null directly inside the query or i must check if the property is available, null, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that like bellow:

```
<select ...>
SELECT * FROM RESULT 
<dynamic prepend="WHERE ">
   <isNull property="id">
      id IS NULL
   </isNull>
   <isNotNull property="id">
     id = #id#
   </isNotNull>
</dynamic>
</select>
```

cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Ibatis throws a NullpointerException when trying to call getId() on that bean if you provide a bean that is null. You must ensure that the bean is not null priorly in your code.